# Active Directory Change Home Folder Path using Power Shell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to change the Home Folder Path and assign it a letter using power shell. I am currently using set-aduser in powershell to change the other parameters in AD. How do you assign it a drive Letter and also assign the Path as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx). The `Set-ADUser` parameters you're looking for are `-HomeDirectory` and `-HomeDrive`:

```psh
Set-ADUser -Identity username -HomeDrive 'P:' -HomeDirectory '\\server\share\username'
```